# How to add minutes to datetime?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to add minutes that already exist in same table. I have a datetime and a duration. I want to get the start date/time as well as the end date/time.

I can use datetime but have to specify 'localtime' which doesn't work. I want the equivalent of DATEADD in SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
datetime(strftime('%s', start_date) + minute_count * 60,  'unixepoch')
```

`start_date` – your start date;

`minute_count` – count of minutes as integer.

Answer (score 17):

This is how you add 15 minutes to the current `datetime`.

```
SELECT datetime('now', '+15 Minute');
```

Comment: well done! For input variables don't use the quotes.
`select datetime(timestamp, '+110 seconds') as ts_corr, * from data;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to e.g. create a new entry in a database you can use the following statement

```
INSERT INTO tablename (created, expires) VALUES (
    datetime('now', 'localtime'),
    datetime('now', 'localtime', '+365 days')
);
```

**datetime** is here actually a shorthand for the **strftime** function. Creating time offsets is achieved with modifierts, there are many more modifiers possible. You can find it here in the documentation for [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)